# Query to group values from two rows in the same column and display count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to the following (using sql-server 2012) :

```
primaryid     Caseid     Indication   Reaction        Drugname
1             2          Pain         Vomiting        DrugA
1             2          Pain         Vomiting        DrugB
3             4          Pain         Headache        DrugA
3             4          Pain         Headache        DrugB
16            17         Pain         Sleepiness      DrugC
16            17         Pain         Sleepiness      DrugD
16            18         Pain         Sleepiness      DrugC
16            18         Pain         Sleepiness      DrugD
```

Please note that primaryid and caseid are NOT unique key identifiers and the values are more or less random, just used to demonstrate the nature of my data. I am interested in knowing if I can query this data to achieve result like the following?:

```
primaryid     Caseid     Indication   Reaction        Drugname        Count
1             2          Pain         Vomiting        DrugA, DrugB     2
3             4          Pain         Headache        DrugA, DrugB     2 
16            17         Pain         Sleepiness      DrugC, DrugD     2
16            18         Pain         Sleepiness      DrugC, DrugD     2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The table above itself is a result of a million joins:) and finally I am stumped at this point.

Comment: Look into TSQL String aggregation (e.g. http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/) this is how you can have a comma separated list. Modify as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @table table (primaryid int, caseid int, indication varchar(10), reaction varchar(10), drugname varchar(10))

insert into @table values (1,2 ,'Pain','Vomiting','DrugA')
insert into @table values (1, 2,'Pain','Vomiting','DrugB')
insert into @table values (3,4,'Pain','Headache','DrugA')
insert into @table values (3,4,'Pain','Headache','DrugB')
insert into @table values (16,17,'Pain','Sleepiness','DrugC')
insert into @table values (16,17,'Pain','Sleepiness','DrugD')
insert into @table values (16,18,'Pain','Sleepiness','DrugC')
insert into @table values (16,18,'Pain','Sleepiness','DrugD')

SELECT
    G.primaryid,
    G.caseid,
    G.indication,
    g.reaction,
    stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + U.drugname
    from @table U
    WHERE U.primaryid = G.primaryid
    and u.caseid = g.caseid
    and u.indication = g.indication
    and u.reaction = g.reaction
    order by U.primaryid
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS drugname,
    count(*) Count
FROM
    @table G
    group by G.primaryid,
    G.caseid,
    G.indication,
    g.reaction
```